# Windows CE 6.0 platform builder copying wrong bib files into postproc directory for fmerge

Tags: platform-builder

I'm trying to add a dll to my nk.bin file.

The problem I am having is that the platform.bib file which is being copied into the postproc directory and used for the fmerge isn't the same as the platform.bib file I have modified in my platform.

When/how does the postproc copy the bib files into the postproc directory.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks,
Steve